# After downloading APK Games weird things happening

Tags: applications, usb-debugging, antivirus

I downloaded APK Games and one thing I know when I woke up my built-in apps were being replaced by "pornclub", "sexyhot", etc. I did Factory data reset but it deleted my built-in apps. I was going to flash it, but I can't enable developer mode by repeatedly tapping the device model (it doesn't work). Also my installer, messenger, and everything are gone. What can I do?

Comment: What's your device & model? After you get done flashing, this is a prime example of how rooting your phone makes it more secure. Had you rooted with SuperSU those games/apks would not have had permission to write/access `su` in order to delete your messenger and dev options. I hope you good luck.

Comment: I recommend backing up any important files to your PC and then using fastboot flash to go back to stock.

Comment: Fastboot needs fastboot mode and without usb debugging you can't flash anything to your device.

Comment: If you boot into fastboot mode by pressing vol and pwr keys you can still run fastboot commands regardless of  debugging settings.

Answer (score 0):

You phone is most certainly infected. The most guaranteed way to get rid of the infection and bring back all the built-in apps you mention is to flash a clean stock ROM. Since you didn't disclose your device information I can't recommend anything further than this.